# What are the correct types for memset function?

Tags: c, char, void-pointers, function-definition, memset

On trying to recreate "memset" function I have error if I try to dereference a void pointer, or have a different type for the second argument than the first. To make the function work I had to change it to:

```c
void ft_memset(unsigned char *st, unsigned char c, size_t n)
```

Is it possible to define the function as in the manual?

```c
void *memset(void *s, int c, size_t n)  <- This is the man version.
```

*I am doing it only with the library stdio.h to use size_t*
*I have to compile wih -Wall -Wextra -Werror*

This is my code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

//stdio.h to use size_t;
//

void *ft_memset(unsigned char *str, unsigned char c, size_t n)
{
    unsigned int i;

    i = 0;
    while (i < n)
    {
        str[i] = c;
        i++;
    }
    return(str);
}
```

Comment: "I have error if I try to dereference a void pointer" What would you expect to happen if you do? Your home-made memset has to cast to a character type internally.

Comment: Is there something wrong with your Standard Library?  You should never need to implement `memset()` yourself.

Comment: @TobySpeight it's OK do rewrite stuff like `memset` for exercise purposes.

Comment: "Is it possible to define the function as in the manual?" Yes. Are you familiar with casts?

Comment: The actual  [`memset`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memset) function will need to cast its arguments anyway (well not really since `void *` pointers are implicitly convertible to any other data pointer type). It also likely do plenty of other things to be optimal, which might include not using bytes in the loop.

Comment: Despite your casting problem, don't use `unsigned int` for `i` when you use `size_t` for `n`, what happens when `n>UINT_MAX`? Use `size_t` for `i`.

Comment: @TobySpeight Someone has to implement `memset()`. Not in this case, but saying that it should never (since everyone is sometimes referred to as yourself) be implemented is a bit strange.

Comment: Have you tried to call the original `memset` without pointer cast? Put any type of pointer as 1st parameter.

Comment: You should post the code you are asking about (the code that does not work).  What can we say about that when you have only posted the alternative that _does_ work!?   You are simply telling us you have some code that does not compile - could be anything!

Comment: Note that if you want `size_t` without creating a false dependency on stdio.h, you should  include stddef.h instead.

Answer (score 5):

The type `void` is incomplete type. You may not dereference a pointer of the type `void *`.

From the C Standard (6.2.5 Types)

> 19 The void type comprises an empty set of values; it is an incomplete
> object type that cannot be completed.

Within the function you just need to cast the pointer of the type `void *` to the type `unsigned char *` before using a loop.

Pay attention to that the second parameter of the standard C function `memset` is `int`.

```
void *memset(void *s, int c, size_t n);
```

Also used by you the type `unsigned int` for the object `i` that plays the role of an index in general is wrong.

```
unsigned int i;
```

The type `unsigned int` can be not large enough to store all values of the type `size_t`. As a result you can get an infinite while loop.

The function can be defined the following way

```
void * memset( void *s, int c, size_t n )
{
    for ( unsigned char *p = s, ch = c; n != 0; n-- )
    {
        *p++ = ch;
    }

    return s;
}
```